# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 При чтении файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть в том, что я шифрую файлы

```
def encrypt_file(self, in_filename, out_filename=None, chunksize=64 * 1024):
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = in_filename + '.enc'

    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    encryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)

    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += bytes(' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16)), 'utf-8')

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

а потом дешифрую

```
def decrypt_file(self, in_filename, out_filename=None, chunksize=24 * 1024):
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = os.path.splitext(in_filename)[0]

    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        origsize = struct.unpack('<Q', infile.read(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
        iv = infile.read(16)
        decryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))

            outfile.truncate(origsize)
    os.remove(in_filename)
```

я уже пробовал ставить кодировки при открытии, примерно как здесь, но безуспешно.

```
with open(in_filename, encoding="utf-8" ,mode ='rb') as infile:
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 231495: character maps to

Comment: На какую конкретно строку указывает ошибка? Приведите полный текст ошибки со стеком вызовов. Для работы с файлами в бинарном режиме указывать кодировку не нужно, при работе с ними перекодировка текста не происходит. Проблема где-то в другом месте.

Comment: ругается он на сам ` with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:`

Comment: А где-то рядом случайно там нет комментария на русском языке? Файл с кодом сохранен в utf-8 или в cp1251?

Comment: к сожалению нет

Comment: У меня ваш код работает нормально, шифрует и дешифрует, никаких ошибок не возникает.

Comment: Хмм, а на каких файлах пробуете?

Comment: Сам же файл с кодом.

Comment: я пробовал на картинках и файлах docx

Comment: Проверил сейчас на png и gif - никаких проблем.

Comment: очень странно...

Comment: Через python3 запускаете?

Comment: Да.............

Comment: Я попробовал практически на всём, что нашел. Всё равно ругается на байт 0x98

Comment: Уберите из кода все, кроме этих двух функций, и проверьте еще раз. Я тестирую на таком коде: https://pastebin.com/7c6RFe92

Comment: Вас просили привести полный стек ошибки. Добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Он полный, т.к другого не имею у меня относительно большая программа, выхожу из положения только через try

Comment: Тоже попробовал. Тоже ошибок не возникает. Win7, Python 3.7.4, crypto-1.4.1 или pycryptodome-3.10.1.

Comment: @GODofZeon А вы **точно** уверены, что ошибка возникает именно с чтением файла после указанного вами `open()`? Других файлов вы не читаете? А то очень похоже, что где-то читается другой файл в текстовом режиме в кодировке отличной от системной без явного указания кодировки. Особенно учитывая тот факт, что что бы вы не шифровали, всегда ругается на символ с кодом 0x98.

Comment: @GODofZeon, ну так удалите try, и приведите в вопросе полный трейсбэк, который выведется. Ну или `import traceback` `traceback.print_exc()` внутри блока `except`. А то это гадание на кофейной гуще. Нужен либо полный код, который можно скопировать к себе и запустить, либо минимальный код и трейсбэк.

Comment: И так, я понял, что и в правду тут всё чисто)) Проблемы со строкой open в основном файле. @insolor приложенька у меня с интерфейсом и она не очень любит ошибки капразничает трейсбэк не выводит и уходит на покой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, что вы где-то читаете совершенно другой файл в текстовом режиме. Причём делаете это в неправильной кодировке. Например, файл в кодировке `utf-8` читаете в Windows без явного указания кодировки (к примеру, у Windows с русской locale кодировка по-умолчанию `cp1251`).

Для теста, я создал файл со смайликом в кодировке `utf-8`. В нём записано всего 4 байта с кодами `\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2`, которые представляют вот этот символ:

Далее, я открывал файл с указанием кодировки и без:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print("utf-8")
    text = f.read()
    print("Done")

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    print("default")
    text = f.read()
    print("Done")
```

И на втором чтении (без указания кодировки) я получил вашу ошибку (и даже на том же самом злополучном байте `0x98`):

```
D:\Programming\Python\1>python codepage.py
utf-8
Done
default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codepage.py", line 8, in <module>
    text = f.read()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 19: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Да, я забыл, что открывал тот же самый файл, но в другом месте, и этот код даже не взаимодействовал